# Cisco AnyConnect: Posture Assessment Failed: CSD library signature verification failed

Tags: 16.04, networking, vpn, cisco

All of a sudden AnyConnect stopped working.

Version 4.5 on ubuntu 16.04.

I'm now getting the following error when trying to connect.

[image]

Any ideas on how to resolve it?